# what is need that ArrayList and Vector implements List directly as AbstractList class has already implemented the List interface?

Tags: java

1. As  we  know  if  super  class  implements  an interface ,
2. then  sub-class  also implicity  implements  that  interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it does mean that you can tell that `ArrayList` and `Vector` implement the `List` API without looking at the source / documentation for `AbstractList`.

In other words, it makes the code / documentation *marginally* easier to understand.

However, that is only a *possible* explanation.  For the real (complete) explanation you would need to ask the designers.